# Finding probability by using combinations

Tags: probability

There are 20 doctors and 15 engineers attending a conference. The number of women doctors and that of women engineers are 12 and 5 respectively. Four participants from this group are selected randomly to chat some sessional panel discussion. Given that two women are selected, find the probability that both of them are doctors.

So I approached the question with 
$$P(\text{Both of the women are doctors}|\text{Both are women}) =
\frac{P(\text{Both women doctors AND Both are women})}{P(\text{Both are women})}$$

$$P(\text{Both women doctors AND both are women}) = \frac{\binom{12}{2}\times\binom{23}{2}}{\binom{35}{4}},$$

$$P(\text{Both are women}) = \frac{\binom{17}{2} \times \binom{18}{2}}{\binom{35}{4}}$$

and afterwards, I'll substitute back the answer in the first equation. Is my method of approaching this question, correct?

Comment: If you type `$$P(x)=\frac{P(\mbox{$x$ and $y$})}{P(y|x)}$$`, you'll get nice formatting: $$P(x)=\frac{P(\mbox{$x$ and $y$})}{P(y|x)}.$$ (What the others do may be apparent, but the `\mbox{}` seems obscure. Without it, however, the "and" would have been typeset as the product of three variables $a$, $n$ and $d$.)

Comment: To be found is: P(all selected women are doctors | 2 women are selected)=P(2 men and 2 female doctors are selected)/P(2 women are selected). Note that this way true events are prescribed. This in contrast with e.g. your "both are women".

Comment: P(2 female doctors, 2 men) = (12 choose 2) * (18 choose 2) / (35 choose 4).

P(2 women selected) = (17 choose 2) * (18 choose 2) / (35 choose 4).

Dividing the first probability by the second, we recover (12 choose 2) / (17 choose 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4$ persons are selected out of $12$ female doctors, $5$ female engineers and $18$ men.

Under the original condition that exactly $2$ women are selected there are$\binom{17}{2}\binom{18}2$ possibilities.

Under the extra condition that the $2$ women are both doctors there are $\binom{12}2\binom{18}2$ possibilities.

So the probability that the extra condition will be satisfied under the original condition is: $$\frac{\binom{12}2\binom{18}2}{\binom{17}{2}\binom{18}2}=\frac{\binom{12}{2}}{\binom{17}{2}}=\frac{12\cdot11}{17\cdot16}=\frac{33}{68}$$